# Update prepared statement not updating

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to update rows using mysqli prepared statements, no error is displayed but it's not updating my rows

```
$c=mysqli_connect('localhost','client','','bdd');
if (!$c) {
    echo 'Erreur de connexion a la base de donnees';
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $faite=1;
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($idg);$i++){
            $var=$idg[$i];
            $update="UPDATE  graissage SET   faite= ? where  id= ? ";
            echo $update;
            $stmt2= mysqli_prepare($c, $update);
            echo mysqli_error($c);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "is", $faite,$var);
            echo mysqli_error($c);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
            echo mysqli_error($c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check if that `$idg[$i]` actually produces IDs that exist in your database? if the `where` doesn't match any records, no updates are done. and note that preparing/binding INSIDE the loop is a waste. you prepare/bind ONCE, then execute multiple times inside the loop. repeated preparation negates one of the primary purposes of prepared statements. and if the $idg array is empty, then the loop doesn't execute at all anyways.

Comment: @MarcB actually it is matching values

Comment: i did tried with one iteration an still not updating @MarcB